# How can I customize the spacing for displaying hierarchy of a project in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I am writing the documentation for a repo and in order to show how files are organized I created a map. This is what I wrote in the editor

[image: what i wrote]

But this is what actually displayed on GitHub

[image: result]

What are my options here to make a good map? Here is a link to [my project on GitHub](https://github.com/JGallardo/dwarf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **br** tags and add triple backticks.

````
```
Level 1
  |
  |- Level 2
      |- Level 3
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use nested lists, like so:

- One

  - One.1
  - One.1
  - One.1
- Two

  - Two.2

    - Two.3

      - Two.4
- Three

  - Three.2

    - Three.3

      - Three.4

        - Three.5

Further reading: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list

Comment: This is also a good approach. I am wondering if your solution is more common in the industry? I just went with my original idea simply as preference after I had seen it somewhere.